# How do I select the first 5 observations with regard to duplicates?

Tags: sas

I have a large dataset containting over 80 000 000 rows sorted by "name" and "income" (with duplicates both for name and income). For the first name I would like to have the 5 lowest incomes. For the second name I would like to have the 5 lowest incomes (but incomes drawn to the first name are then disqualified to be selected). And so on, until the last name (if there are any incomes left at that time).

Comment: Can you post an example of what your data looks like? And what you want the result to be?

Comment: By "drawn" do mean "tied with"?  That is you want the lowest 5 distinct income levels?

Comment: Yes, I mean tied with!

Comment: Does it matter which observation you get when there are ties in INCOME?   If so what is the criteria for picking only one observation?

Comment: Person 1 have income values 150, 200, 300, 400, 500 and 600. Person 2 have income values 100, 300, 600, 700, 900, 1100, 1400 and 1500. Then I want Person 1 to receive 150, 200, 300, 400, 500 and Person 2 to receive 100, 600, 700, 900 and 1100. Did this make it more clear? :)

Comment: So you don't have duplicate records with the same Person and Income?  What do you want to do it Person X has only 5 observations and all five values of Income have already been "used" be earlier people?

Comment: No, there aren't any records with the same person and income. In your example Person X would be without income (the person would not exist at all in the outfile).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data have;
   do n = 1 to 8e5;
      do _N_ = 1 to 100;
         income = ceil(rand('uniform') * 1e4);
         address = cats('Address_', _N_);
         output;
      end;
   end;
run;

data want(drop=c);

   if _N_ = 1 then do;
      dcl hash h(dataset : 'have(obs=0)', ordered : 'a', multidata : 'y');
      h.definekey('income');
      h.definedata(all : 'y');
      h.definedone();
      dcl hiter i('h');

      dcl hash inc();
      inc.definekey('income');
      inc.definedone();
   end;

   do until (last.n);
      set have;
      by n;
      h.add();
   end;

   do c = 0 by 0 while (i.next() = 0);
      if inc.add() = 0 then do;
         c + 1;
         output;
      end;
      if c = 5 then leave;
   end;

   _N_ = i.first();
   _N_ = i.prev();
   h.clear();    

run;
```

Answer (score 1):

You first want to rank income within names. So:

```
proc rank data=yourdata out=temp ties=low;
   by name;
   var income;
   ranks incomerank;
run;
```

Then you want to filter the 5 lowest incomes by name, so:

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select distinct *
from temp 
where incomerank < 6;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to sort and track incomes

- Use an `array` to sort and track the lowest five `income` of a `name`.
- Use a `hash` to track and check the observance of an `income` being `output` and thus ineligible for output by later names.

Example:

An insert sort of eligible low valued incomes is used and will be fast due to only 5 items.

```
data have;
  call streaminit(1234);
  do name = 1 to 1e6;
    do seq = 1 to rand('integer', 20);
      income = rand('integer', 20000, 1000000);
      output;
    end;
  end;
run;

data
  want (label='Lowest 5 incomes (first occurring over all names) of each name')
  want_barren(keep=name label='Names whose all incomes were previously output for earlier names')
;
  array X(5) _temporary_;

  if _n_ = 1 then do;
    if 0 then set have;
    declare hash incomes();
    incomes.defineKey('income');
    incomes.defineDone();
  end;

  _maxmin5 = 1e15;
  x(1) = 1e15;
  x(2) = 1e15;
  x(3) = 1e15;
  x(4) = 1e15;
  x(5) = 1e15;

  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.name);
    set have;
    by name;

    if incomes.check() = 0 then continue;

    * insert sort - lowest five not observed previously;

    if income > _maxmin5 then continue;

    do _i_ = 1 to 5;
      if income < x(_i_) then do;
        do _j_ = 5 to _i_+1 by -1;
          x(_j_) = x(_j_-1);
        end;
        x(_i_) = income;
        _maxmin5 = x(5);
        incomes.add();
        leave;
      end;
    end;
  end;

  _outflag = 0;
  do _n_ = 1 to _n_;
    set have;

    if income in x then do;
      _outflag = 1;
      OUTPUT want;
    end;
  end;

  if not _outflag then 
    OUTPUT want_barren;

  drop _:;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my interpretation of your problem and a solution.

Suppose a simplified version of your data looks like this and you want the 2 lowest income for each name. For simplicity, I use a numeric variable `n` as name, but a character var will work as well.

```
data have;
input n income;
datalines;
1 100
1 200
1 300
2 400
2 100
2 500
3 600
3 200
3 500
;
```

From this data, my guess is that your logic goes like this:

- Start with n = 1.
- Output the 2 observations with the lowest income (100 and 200)
- Go to the next name (n=2).
- Output the 2 observations with the lowest income, that has not already been output (300 and 400). 200 Has been output in the n=1 group.
- ...And so on...

This gives the desired result below:

```
data want;
input n income;
datalines;
1 100
1 200
2 300
2 400
3 500
;
```

Try out the solution below and verify that you get the result as posted above.

```
data want(drop=c);

   if _N_ = 1 then do;
      dcl hash h(ordered : 'a', multidata : 'y');
      h.definekey('income');
      h.definedone();
      dcl hiter i('h');

      dcl hash inc();
      inc.definekey('income');
      inc.definedone();
   end;

   do until (last.n);
      set have;
      by n;
      h.add();
   end;

   do c = 0 by 0 while (i.next() = 0);
      if inc.add() = 0 then do;
         c + 1;
         output;
      end;
      if c = 2 then leave;
   end;

   _N_ = i.first();
   _N_ = i.prev();
   h.clear();    

run;
```

Finally, let us create representable example data with 80Mio obs. I change the `if c = 2 then leave;` statement to `if c = 5 then leave;` to go back to your actual problem.

The code below runs in about 45 sec on my system and processes the data in a single pass. Let me know is it works for you :-)

```
data have;
   do n = 1 to 8e5;
      do _N_ = 1 to 100;
         income = ceil(rand('uniform') * 1e4);
         output;
      end;
   end;
run;

data want(drop=c);

   if _N_ = 1 then do;
      dcl hash h(ordered : 'a', multidata : 'y');
      h.definekey('income');
      h.definedone();
      dcl hiter i('h');

      dcl hash inc();
      inc.definekey('income');
      inc.definedone();
   end;

   do until (last.n);
      set have;
      by n;
      h.add();
   end;

   do c = 0 by 0 while (i.next() = 0);
      if inc.add() = 0 then do;
         c + 1;
         output;
      end;
      if c = 5 then leave;
   end;

   _N_ = i.first();
   _N_ = i.prev();
   h.clear();    

run;
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems to work except that the other variables in the file (besides name and income) come out wrong. For example, I get the same address variable on the first 5 rows, another address variable on the next 5 rows

Comment: Just added another answer to accommodate this. Did this in a separate answer as the first one got quite long :-)

Comment: Yes, worked perfectly!! Thanks again!

Comment: Anytime :-) Please remember to close the thread.